# groupby scala list of string

Tags: scala, group-by

I am facing a problem to calculate the sum of elements in Scala having the same title (my key in this case).

Currently my input can be described as:

```
val listInput1 = 
  List(
    "itemA,CATA,2,4 ",
    "itemA,CATA,3,1 ",
    "itemB,CATB,4,5",
    "itemB,CATB,4,6"
   )

val listInput2 = 
  List(
    "itemA,CATA,2,4 ",
    "itemB,CATB,4,5",
    "itemC,CATC,1,2"
  )
```

The required output for lists in input should be

```
val listoutput1 = 
  List(
    "itemA,CATA,5,5 ",
    "itemB,CATB,8,11"
  )

val listoutput2 =
  List(
    "itemA , CATA, 2,4 ",
    "itemB,CATB,4,5",
    "itemC,CATC,1,2"
  )
```

I wrote the following function:

```
def sumByTitle(listInput: List[String]): List[String] =      
  listInput.map(_.split(",")).groupBy(_(0)).map { 
    case (title, features) => 
       "%s,%s,%d,%d".format(
         title,
         features.head.apply(1),
         features.map(_(2).toInt).sum,
         features.map(_(3).toInt).sum)}.toList
```

It doesn't give me the expected result as it changes the order of lines.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Is that guaranteed that the in the list we will always get the input in sorted order, like first team A then B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListMap` is designed to preserve the order of items inserted to the `Map`.

```
import collection.immutable.ListMap

def sumByTitle(listInput: List[String]): List[String] = {
  val itemPttrn = raw"(.*)(\d+),(\d+)\s*".r
  listInput.foldLeft(ListMap.empty[String, (Int,Int)].withDefaultValue((0,0))) {
    case (lm, str) =>
      val itemPttrn(k, a, b) = str  //unsafe
      val (x, y) = lm(k)
      lm.updated(k, (a.toInt + x, b.toInt + y))
  }.toList.map { case (k, (a, b)) => s"$k$a,$b" }
}
```

This is a bit unsafe in that it will throw if the input string doesn't match the regex pattern.

```
sumByTitle(listInput1)
//res0: List[String] = List(itemA,CATA,5,5, itemB,CATB,8,11)

sumByTitle(listInput2)
//res1: List[String] = List(itemA,CATA,2,4, itemB,CATB,4,5, itemC,CATC,1,2)
```

You'll note that the trailing space, if there is one, is not preserved.

Comment: Hello all the spaces in the required output are a mistake . I corrected it . May you please change the code

Comment: @scalacode; No code changes needed. Input format is preserved in the output except for any trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in sorting you can simply return the `sorted` list:

```
val listInput1 = 
  List(
    "itemA , CATA, 2,4 ",
    "itemA , CATA, 3,1 ",
    "itemB,CATB,4,5",
    "itemB,CATB,4,6"
   )

val listInput2 = 
  List(
    "itemA , CATA, 2,4 ",
    "itemB,CATB,4,5",
    "itemC,CATC,1,2"
  )

def sumByTitle(listInput: List[String]): List[String] =      
  listInput.map(_.split(",")).groupBy(_(0)).map { 
    case (title, features) => 
       "%s,%s,%d,%d".format(
         title,
         features.head.apply(1),
         features.map(_(2).trim.toInt).sum,
         features.map(_(3).trim.toInt).sum)}.toList.sorted

println("LIST 1")
sumByTitle(listInput1).foreach(println)

println("LIST 2")
sumByTitle(listInput2).foreach(println)
```

You can find the code [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1Pwpft0RQJahQobBMJ3VfA) for you to play around with.

---

As a side note, you may be interested in separating the serialization and deserialization from your business logic.

[Here you can find another Scastie notebook](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vT2huoPoS0Cq04Xjzm5vLQ) with a relatively naive approach for a first step towards separating concerns.

Comment: my aim is not to sort , I just want to keep the same order as the list in input.

Comment: As far as I understood the order of the accumulated results should resemble the order of the elements in the original list. It does not mean that the elements in the original list are sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foldByTitle(listInput: List[String]): List[Item] =
  listInput.map(Item.parseItem).foldLeft(List.empty[Item])(sumByTitle)

val sumByTitle: (List[Item], Item) => List[Item] = (acc, curr) =>
  acc.find(_.name == curr.name).fold(curr :: acc) { i =>
    acc.filterNot(_.name == curr.name) :+ i.copy(num1 = i.num1 + curr.num1, num2 = i.num2 + curr.num2)
  }

case class Item(name: String, category: String, num1: Int, num2: Int)
object Item {
  def parseItem(serializedItem: String): Item = {
    val itemTokens = serializedItem.split(",").map(_.trim)
    Item(itemTokens.head, itemTokens(1), itemTokens(2).toInt, itemTokens(3).toInt)
  }
}
```

This way the initial order of the elements to kept.

Comment: is there a chance I can do it with just one function , no need for case calss here